# Javascript not Jquery reading next SPAN tag Value from a SPAN Tag containing specific Text

Tags: javascript

I have following HTML and I need to read the SPAN Tag value of the next SPAN tag following a specific Tag containing a text:-

```
<div data-component-id="ghkzq6qysz8y"
     class="component-inner-container status-green "
     data-component-status="operational"
     data-js-hook="">

   <span class="name">
      Address Validation
   </span>


  <span
    class="component-status "
    title=""
  >
    Operational
  </span>
```

I need to read the SPAN TAG value of Component-Status of a specific SPAN Tag containing value "Address Validation". I can't use jQuery and this has to be done in JavaScript. In jQuery I could have used:

```
var apistatus =($('span:contains("Address Validation")').next('span').text());
```

Can someone help me with plain JavaScript how this can be achieved.

Comment: Not sure if it helps you, but here's [how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5a3e0664d261422f11a78faaf101d70c73b3a5a8/src/traversing.js#L120).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let spanValue = document.querySelector("span.name + span").innerText;`

We use "+" to select [the next immediate sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) of a specific element, in this case a span which is the next sibling of a span with the class "name".

Answer (score 1):

```
var apistatus = document.getElementsByClassName("component-status")[0].innerText;
```

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will solve the problem, along with the code to make more contextual.